# Click event in event listener written in Google Closure not working?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library, google-material-icons

I am new to Java**Script**, My question is when I try this JS in chrome browser console it works, But in my JS file it's not working

I attached the code, For HTML design I used google MDL, For JS I used **Google Closure**

HTML :

```
<HTML>
 <head>
    <script src="../closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/add.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/material.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test_add.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div>
     <button id="add" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">
       <i class="material-icons">add</i>
     </button>
   </div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

JS:

```
goog.provide('sample.add');

goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.events');

sample.add = function() {
    self = this;
};
goog.inherits(sample.add, goog.base);
sample.add.prototype.bindEvent = function() {
    goog.events.listen(goog.dom.getElement('add'),
         goog.events.EventType.CLICK, function(e) {
            alert("HAPPY");
    });
};
```

What is wrong with this code

1. When I try without `goog.provide` and `goog.require` its show error to all
2. When I use this there is no reaction to the click event
3. Is there any other best resource to see online

Kindly help me

Comment: Have you called `bindEvent` anywhere? Also adding it as a property of `sample.add.prototype` makes it an inherited method of objects created by calling  `sample.add ` as a constructor. Is this the intention?

Comment: Where should i call this bindEvent method to achieve the click event

I can't understand,
sample.add.prototype makes it an inherited method of objects created by calling sample.add as a constructor. Is this the intention?

Comment: Please include in the question a reference to the `bindEvent` documentation you are using to write the function, or the tutorial where you have seen it used.

Comment: My point is simple,  I need  alert or some function should done when i click add button in html,  I need to use goog. events. listen method to do this not native javascript or jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's a few things I'd change here.

The biggest issue is that you're never calling sample.add or sample.add.bindEvent.

Then, your script will have to be moved to below your button, so that the button will be on the page when your script runs. Or you could use JS to delay the script running, up to you, but I will say, its pretty common to see scripts just before the end of the body tag.

```
<HTML>
 <head>
    <script src="../closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/material.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test_add.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div>
     <button id="add" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">
       <i class="material-icons">add</i>
     </button>
   </div>
   <script src="../js/add.js"></script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Also, I'd ditch the goog.base call, unless you specifically need that. If you do need that, please explain why and maybe we can help.

Finally we just need a few subtle tweaks;

```
goog.provide('sample.add');

goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.events');
/** @export */
sample.add = function() {
    self = this;
    self.bindEvent();
};
sample.add.prototype.bindEvent = function() {
    goog.events.listen(goog.dom.getElement('add'),
         goog.events.EventType.CLICK, function(e) {
            alert("HAPPY");
    });
};
sample.add();
```

I suppose you could call sample.add.bindEvent directly, but I felt like this was probably just the first step to something larger and you'd want to go this way.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, It worked but in JS  this. add. prototype. bindEvent() ; instead of this. bindEvents() ; Can i know why